# Displaying a column vector with the value of 'i' modifies every value

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I am attempting to build a column vector with the following values:

```
my_vector = [2.7; -5; 8.4*10^9; 4 + 3i]
```

Unfortunately, this approach does *not* display the values above when printed, but rather results in the following:

```
my_vector =

   1.0e+09 *

   0.0000 + 0.0000i
  -0.0000 + 0.0000i
   8.4000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 - 0.0000i
```

This looks nothing like I was expecting and I'm not sure why.

```
format long
vec2 = [2.7 -5 8.4*10^9 4 + 3i]';
vec2

vec2 =

   1.0e+09 *

  0.000000002700000 + 0.000000000000000i
 -0.000000005000000 + 0.000000000000000i
  8.400000000000000 + 0.000000000000000i
  0.000000004000000 - 0.000000003000000i
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot the sign in the exponent. Then, the large number is preventing you from seeing the smaller ones. Try `format long` to see more decimals

Comment: OK. I edited the code, but the output still looks unfamiliar. Should the output more close match the initial vector values?

Comment: The output exactly matches the initial values. The exponent in the displayed output affects all displayed values

Comment: Thank you Luis!

Comment: Also, `'` does a complex conjugate transpose. This is why your `4 + 3i` becomes `4 - 3i`. Use `.'` to transpose without taking the complex conjugate. Or write your vector as `[x; y; z; ...]` (semicolons separate rows).